# Working example of using Twitter API on Android?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

Could anyone suggest a working example of how Twitter API is implemented in Android. I would like to login and post on Twitter.

After some research [Twitter4j library for Java](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) is probably the best choice, however, I still don't manage to get Twitter login working.

I found a few examples, like

- [posting on Twitter example](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/comment-page-2/#comment-10454)
- [another example](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/)
- [one more example](https://github.com/ppierson/T4JTwitterLogin)
- [one more example](https://github.com/ppierson/T4JTwitterLogin)

However, they are depreciated and not working. Could anyone suggest a working example of how posting on Twitter from Android app is implemented?